# IE8 compatibility for JSF / Richfaces Application

Tags: jsf, internet-explorer-8, richfaces, internet-explorer-6, compatibility

I have JSF / Richfaces web app. This application was originally intended for **IE6 Browser**. Now we have to port it to **IE-8** as well. The App Server is Weblogic 10.3. I tried the below solutions.

1. A filter to add Header param,  X-UA-Compatible.
2. JSF PhaseListener to add header param, X-UA-Compatible.
3. Added Meta tag in the first line of head in the page.

None of the above works. Also I'm unable to any custom header values. HttpRequestWrapper doesn't work as well.

Please suggest solutions. I always wish I could use scriptlets in JSF or logic tags anywhere in JSF.

Comment: The x-ua-compatible tag should do what it's expected; can you show us how you used it? Did you set it to EmulateIE6?

Comment: I added <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5">   as the first line in head. But in the rendered code, this appears after JSF css and scriptlets.

Answer (score 0):

The `X-UA-Compatible` option in IE8 can only work as a fall-back for IE7 compatibility. It does not have an option to emulate IE6.

Because of this, the situation you're in -- having an intranet app that is written for IE6 and does not work in IE8 -- is one of the main reasons why companies have stuck with IE6 for so long: it can be quite hard to upgrade.

The ideal solution, of course, is to update the code in your site so that it works in IE8 (or better yet, IE9). This can be a long and expensive process, but there's no official short-cut solution.

If you can't update your site, you will have to stick with IE6. But there are some solutions that might make that less painful.

The obvious quick-fix answer is to upgrade your main platforms to IE8 or IE9, but continue to run IE6, keeping in a virtual machine, and use it just for the specific site(s) that need it. There's also the ultra-cheap option of IETester, which is an app that can run multiple versions of IE on the same machine (including IE6). However IETester is known to crash frequently, so is probably not an ideal solution. It's good for testing a site in various IE versions, but not for actually getting useful work done.

These would be stop-gap measures at best, but will keep you running while allowing you to upgrade the rest of your infrastructure.

A slightly more robust answer might come in the form of [Browsium](http://www.browsium.com/). This is a product launched by some ex-Microsoft engineers, aimed at helping old IE6-specific sites work in newer versions of Explorer. [See also this article](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/04/04/browsium_mhrc/) for a good real-world example of what they can do.

In the long term, you will have to update your site eventually; IE6 can't last forever, even with solutions like Browsium. But these solutions will allow you to hold back from having to make changes in the short term.

If you're making the upgrade now, I would strongly suggest skipping IE8 and moving straight to IE9 if at all possible. IE8 is already obsolete, and will cause similar upgrade issues to IE6 (although probably not quite as bad) when its support ends.

Comment: Thanks for your response!!  1. I'm afraid we have to migrate to IE8 and **maintain backward compatibility** with IE6 as well. Skipping IE8 and moving to IE9 is out of question.  
2. This meta tag works properly in a Struts Based Application but not in JSF / Richfaces. Thanks for scriptlet / logic tags I can specific issues easily.

Comment: Hello @SKR  no need to add meta tag in xhtml just put just see my above answer it will solve all problem

Answer (score 0):

For Hide CompitibilityView Button in IE 8 9 In Jsf you just have to put this  code in your PhaseListner Implemented Class

`@Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event)
    {
         response.addHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=edge");
        }`

   Simply Add this line in Implemented PhaseListner class

Comment: Thanks Jigar Patel. I will it and respond ASAP.

Comment: @Jigar: your caps lock is hanging and now it look like you're screaming like an annoying little kid. This is unprofessional. I suggest to delete the comment and re-type it carefully with caps lock turned off. By the way, nagging for the checkmark is relatively rude if the OP hasn't yet confirmed if the answer has *actually* helped in solving the problem and also if the OP is *already* familiar with how the system works.